# Select to extract domain from website (MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need return the domain from a website. As sample we have the folwoing one:

```
www.website.com
www.website.eu
```

The result that I need is **com** and **eu**

I have the following select below:

```
SELECT INSTR((RIGHT(fldwebsite,3)), '.') AS fldDomain, fldwebsite
FROM tblwebsite;
```

With this I can know in with position is the last dot but know I am fighting to return the last part...

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions of Access I believe you would use Mid, in 2013 onwards you can use Substring:

```
SELECT Replace(Mid(RIGHT(fldwebsite,3), INSTR((RIGHT(fldwebsite,3)), '.') + 1), '.','') AS fldDomain, fldwebsite
FROM tblwebsite;
```

OR

```
SELECT Replace(Substring(RIGHT(fldwebsite,3), INSTR((RIGHT(fldwebsite,3)), '.') + 1,3), '.','') AS fldDomain, fldwebsite
FROM tblwebsite;
```

Comment: Hi Christian, Thanks a lot for your feedback... I am using Access 2010. The first select returns exactly the same content on fldwebsite!? The second one I think that I cannot use SubString...!?

Comment: @NunoOliveira Try the revised and see if that works?

Comment: Hi Christian, it works perfect. Thanks a lot. Have a nice week.

Comment: No Problem @NunoOliveira, if you'd like to accept the answer so that it becomes closed that would be great. Cheers :)